# Install ruby2.2.3 with RVM on ubuntu 21.04

Tags: apt, ruby, 21.04

I trying to install Ruby 2.2.3 in Ubuntu 21.04 with rvm but I get stuck in the dependencies, libssl1.0-dev. I tried some tips found in [this link](https://www.garron.me/en/linux/install-ruby-2-3-3-ubuntu.html):

- Edit this file /etc/apt/sources.list and add this line to the end of it.

  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main
- After that run:

  sudo apt update && apt-cache policy libssl1.0-dev

But I get stuck in two errors:

First when I not add the trusted option in sources.list:

```
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Hit:9 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Second when i add the trusted option in the sourcers.list file:

```
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
libssl1.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6
  Version table:
     1.0.2n-1ubuntu5.6 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
```

After that I will not be able to continue, every time that I run

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com. --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
```

I will receive this error

```
Server indicate a failure
```

I tried with other servers like:

1. hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net
2. hkp://pgp.mit.edu
3. hkp://keyserver.pgp.com

But none of them worked, someone can help me?

Comment: Ruby 2.2.3 is EOL, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is EOL. Why do you think you need them?

Comment: Because I have to maintain a project with Ruby 2.2.3 and just can't upgrade

Comment: Yes, with that I was able to install libssl0-dev, would you like to post your comment as the answer? @karel

Comment: @LucasLuandeMelo There's no need for me to repost what's already been covered in the answers to the canonical question, but If there is any new material that hasn't been covered in the canonical question I would prefer to post a new answer there instead.

Comment: Understood, thanks for explaining. @karel